# Why would false not be defined in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, js-test-driver

I'm using [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/index.html) in conjunction to [Js-test-driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) using [an adapter](https://github.com/ibolmo/jasmine-jstd-adapter) to connect them both.

I've got the following test case:

```
describe("Undefined false", function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        var undefFalse = false;
    });

    it("should return a defined value", function(){
        expect(this.undefFalse).toBeDefined();
    });

    it("should return false", function(){
        expect(this.undefFalse).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

Whereas the second test succeeds as expected, the first fails with the following error:

> Undefined false test.test that it should return a defined value failed
>   (0,00  ms): AssertError: Expected
>   undefined to be defined.

Why is it that `false` should be `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about jasmine but this:

```
var undefFalse = false; // local variable

this.undefFalse; // property of an object(?)
```

will obviously not work.

Make sure to either get rid of the `this.` in the asserts, or set `undefFalse` on the correct object.

Comment: Without the `this` on the second assertion, the second test `toBeFalsy` would fail. However, after reading your answer I changed the declaration to `this.undefFalse = false` and both test succeeded. My worry is that I might misuse `this` ...

Comment: I don't think that you misuse `this` here, `this` refers to the test case in this case, so there shouldn't be any problem :)